# How to get rows and columns from external Excel file - JAVA?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, xlsx

I tried to read some data from an external Excel file (.xlsx) into my Java code (IDE: Eclipse) but I can't understand how to get values from only one column, identified by column name.

Someone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Tried with following snippets:

```
public void readXLSX(String excelPath) throws IOException {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(excelPath));
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        for (Sheet sheet : wb) {
        int countRows = countTotalRows(sheet);
        System.out.println("countRows: " + countRows);
        int countCells = countTotalCells(sheet);
        System.out.println("countCells: " + countCells);
        }
        //      readlAllWorksheet(itr);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    
    private int countTotalCells(Sheet sheet) {
    List<Cell> listCells = new ArrayList<>(); 
    try {

        int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        for (int index = firstRow + 1; index <= lastRow; index++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(index);
        System.out.println();
        if (row != null) {
            for (int cellIndex = row.getFirstCellNum(); cellIndex < row.getLastCellNum(); cellIndex++) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellIndex, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            printCellValue(cell);
            listCells.add(cell);
            }
        }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return listCells.size();
    }
    return listCells.size();
    }

    private  void printCellValue(Cell cell) {
    CellType cellType = cell.getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.FORMULA)
        ? cell.getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum() : cell.getCellTypeEnum();
    if (cellType.equals(CellType.STRING)) {
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " | ");
    }
    if (cellType.equals(CellType.NUMERIC)) {
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue() + " | ");
        } else {
        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " | ");
        }
    }
    if (cellType.equals(CellType.BOOLEAN)) {
        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " | ");
    }
    }
```

In which way can i get column from the Excel, identified by column name, as 'ORDERS'?
I'm working with jdk1.8

That's my output right now:

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkgJK.png)

Comment: Try looking at [Are there any methods to read cells in a particular column in excel using java?](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-methods-to-read-cells-in-a-particular-column-in-excel-using-java)

Comment: This is what you tried, and what is the current result?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson result is that, if I'm going to print all in console, I got all the content of the Excel.

Comment: @AliasCartellano I've found some answers like ones that you've posted but I would like to  use some native method, maybe from some external framework?

Comment: Can you add the current output? That would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson putted the output in the question, as image.